# fractional ideals of a number field - can they be multiplied by an integer to land in $\mathcal{O}_K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field (i.e a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$) and $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers, and $I \subseteq K$ a fractional ideal, by which I mean/define an finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_K$-submodule of $K$. On can show there exists $r \in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $rI \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$, which is why $I$ is called a fractional ideal. My question is can we find such $r \in \mathbb{Z}$? My guess is yes. 
Here is my reason: it is a basic fact that for every $k \in K$, there is an integer $n$ such that $nk \in \mathcal{O}_K$ (take the minimal poly of $k$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and clear denominators ... the $n$ is cooked up from these).
Let $g_1, \cdots, g_m$ be the generators of $I$ as an $\mathcal{O}_K$-module. For each $g_i$, we can find a $n_i$ such that $n_ig_i \in \mathcal{O}_K$. Let $r=\prod n_i$. Then $rg_i \in \mathcal{O}_K$, so $rI \in \mathcal{O}_K$. Is this correct? I fear it is not, since the source I'm reading keeps taking $r \in \mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: Your proof is ok. (See also [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/idealfactor.pdf), Theorem 2.3(2).)

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for the answer, and for the reference!